# Regex : replace quotes except inside curly brackets

Tags: regex, sed

Here is an example of markdown text:

> # "My title"
>
> !Image caption.{ style="float:right; width: 20%; border:
> 1px"}
>
> Some "quoted text", some *"emphasized text"*, etc.

In a bash script, I'm trying to replace any double quotes with french quotes.

For example: "word" should become « word ».

In other words, all the quotes before a word should be replaced with an opened french quote followed by a non-breaking space; and all the quotes after a word should be replaced with a non-breaking space followed by a closed french quote; EXCEPT when the quotes are inside of curly brackets.

So the previous markdown text should be converted like this:

> # « My title »
>
> !Image caption.{ style="float:right; width: 20%; border:
> 1px"}
>
> Some « quoted text », some *« emphasized text »*, etc.

### What I've tried

I currently use the following regex in my script:

```
" Replace "word by « word
sed -i -Ee "/(^|\s|\(|\[)\"/ s//\1« /g" myfile.md
" Replace word" by word »
sed -i -Ee "/(\S)\"/ s//\1 »/g" myfile.md
```

Of course, the problem is that it replaces all the quotes, even inside of curly brackets.

So my question is: which regex could replace double quotes with french quotes, except inside of curly brackets ?

Comment: Better use a programming language where the engine supports e.g. `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` like `PHP`, `PyPi` regex, etc. See https://regex101.com/r/1C9lFg/1 and https://regex101.com/r/1C9lFg/2

Comment: You could use `(?:"(?=.*?{.*?})|"(?=[^}]*?$))` to select all quotes outside brackets but since frenchquotes are different on the left/right it seems you'd need something more sofisticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk:`

```
awk -F "" '
{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){                    # loop over all fields/characters in line
    if ($i=="{") brace++                  # increment counter if `{` found
    if ($i=="}") brace--                  # decrement counter if `}` found
    if (brace==0 && $i=="\""){            # if counter is zero and char is a quote
      printf "%s", (cquote ? " »" : "« ") # print closing or opening french quote
      cquote=!cquote                      # toggle flag
      continue                            # continue with next character
    }
    printf "%s", $i                       # print character
  }
  print ""                                # print newline
}' file
```

Output:

```
# « My title »

!Image caption.{ style="float:right; width: 20%; border: 1px"}

Some « quoted text », some *« emphasized text »*, etc.
```

Comment: This is nice, but the problem is it doesn't take into account the position of the quotes to replace them, it's just one out of two is opened, one out of two is closed... So if the file contains any additional (bad) quotes, it will fail everywhere else... That's why I had thought about this for my regex: if a word is at the beginning of a line, or is preceded by a space or a ( or a [, then the quotes should be opened frenchquotes; in any other case, it should be closed frenchquotes. Would there be a way to integrate both approaches?

Comment: Exactly. This code also doesn't handle nested quotes in a particular way. It expects one opening and one closing quote.

Comment: Nested quotes are rare enough to not be a problem... Me doing typos, at the contrary, is pretty regular, so I'd really like a solution that could take care of the quotes according to their relative position to the word...

Comment: I tried to implement that (if previous character is a space, `[` or `)` or if at the beginning of a line, then use an opening french quote) and it turns `*"emphasized text"*` to `* »emphasized text »*` (no opening quote because of `*`). What now? More rules?

Comment: No, no more rules. You made me think twice; and you're absolutely right! I want to keep it simple. So, thank you very much for your help!